# What does May mean by "inductively" choosing paths in van Kampen's proof?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am reading the fundamental group (not groupoid!) version of May's categorical proof van Kampen'd theorem. I am having trouble understanding what he means by "inductively" choosing paths here:

> The inclusion of categories $J \colon \pi_1(X,x) \to \Pi(X)$ is an equivalence. An inverse equivalence $F : \Pi(X) \to \pi_1(X,x)$ is determined by a choice of path classes $x \to y$ for $y \in X$; we choose $c_x$ when $y=x$ and so ensure that $F\circ J=\mathrm{Id}$. **Because the cover $\mathscr O$ is finite and closed under finite intersections, we can choose our paths inductively so that the path $x \to y$ lies entirely in $U$ whenever $y$ is in $U$.**

I am not able to understand what is being done in the statement that is bolded out. All I am getting is that the paths $\gamma_y\colon x\to y$ are being chosen so that $\gamma_y$ lies entirely in some $U$, but this doesn't use finiteness of $\mathscr O$ for each $U\in\mathscr O$ is path-connected. I surely am missing something essential here, something relating to "inductively" and the fact that $\mathscr O$ is finite. Can someone nudge me towards the correct thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May chooses the path $\gamma_y\colon x\to y$ such that for any $U\in \mathcal{O}$ that contains $y$, $\gamma_y$ lies in $U$. To do this, just take the intersection of all $U\in \mathcal{O}$ that contain $y$. By the assumptions this intersection is again in $\mathcal{O}$ and since $\mathcal{O}$ consists of path connected sets, it contains a path from $x$ to $y$.